# php natural order sorting of mysql select rows

Tags: php, mysql, natural-sort

I'm running a select that returns alphanumeric results, e.g:

```
ABC-1
ABC-2
ABC-10
SAM-1
SAM-2
SAM-10
SAM-20
```

I've tried using:

```
ORDER BY CAST(mid(field_name, 6, LENGTH(class) -5) AS unsigned)
```

and

```
ORDER BY filed_name + 0 ASC
```

this has helped put some order but I cant seem to order -2 before -10

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
ORDER BY 
  LEFT(field_name, INSTR(field_name, '-') - 1),
  CAST(
    SUBSTRING(field_name, INSTR(field_name, '-') + 1) AS INTEGER
  )
```

Comment: @Digital Craft Studios: And that would be… which error, exactly?

Comment: Line: 130 Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CAST( RIGHT(`class`, LENGTH(`class`) - INSTR(`class`, '-')) AS INTEGER' at line 4

Comment: @Digital Craft Studios: It seems you have not noticed that I had changed my answer a bit. Please try again.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm unable to hug you! works like charm thanks... could you refer me to any resource that could teach how to solve queries like these? Thanks a milliom